# kafka streaming application does not consume all the topics and does not throw error

Tags: spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have written java springboot kafka stream processor application (Kubernetes 1 pod, scaled to 3 to see if that helps, the incoming messages increase after 12 AM) which has several input destinations and several output destinations, the application was running fine while I was testing (at a time I had enabled one in-0-destination and 1 out-0-destination) , when I deployed on dev environment , I have observed that it consumes from 1 topic and does not consume message from other topics at all. I am new to kafka streams, there are few things I am not sure if I am doing it wrong here  , I do not see any exceptions or errors but did notice, it endlessly shows the below lines in logs  , I have read several webpages that are talking about REBALANCING issue

few log lines -

```
INFO 2023-03-20T05:19:16.765840655Z [resource.labels.containerName: app] o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator | [Consumer clientId=app1-0c725685-e7e5-47db-9d20-b8bab43d9eaa-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=app1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing
INFO 2023-03-20T05:19:13.902115838Z [resource.labels.containerName: app] o.a.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams | stream-client [app1-7aad2209-2b6d-4e0a-bdca-8739905eb66a] State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING
INFO 2023-03-20T05:19:13.901956567Z [resource.labels.containerName: app] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [app1--7aad2209-2b6d-4e0a-bdca-8739905eb66a-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to RUNNING
INFO 2023-03-20T05:19:13.901643975Z [resource.labels.containerName: app] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [app1-7aad2209-2b6d-4e0a-bdca-8739905eb66a-StreamThread-1] Restoration took 100 ms for all tasks []
INFO 2023-03-20T05:19:13.899467996Z [resource.labels.containerName: app] o.a.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams | stream-client [app1-6c573676-a2ad-4aef-8303-126211f1661b] State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING
INFO 2023-03-20T05:19:13.899339816Z [resource.labels.containerName: app] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [app1-6c573676-a2ad-4aef-8303-126211f1661b-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to RUNNING
INFO 2023-03-20T05:19:13.899220957Z [resource.labels.containerName: app] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [app1-6c573676-a2ad-4aef-8303-126211f1661b-StreamThread-1] Restoration took 101 ms for all tasks []
INFO 2023-03-20T05:19:13.899099307Z [resource.labels.containerName: app] o.a.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams | stream-client [app1-5176beed-c5cb-411a-a041-6dd51833bcde] State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING
```

I am not sure if this behaviour is correct.

This is what I have tried so far

- I have tested each input + output kafka topic combination and this worked fine
- I have changed the output destination partitions from 3 to 6 (input partition was 6)
- I have scaled the kubernetes pod from 1 - 3 (going to observe it)

I have around 10 input and 10 output destination kafka topics , the output kafka topic destinations are dynamically changed (name change, topics pre-exist on kafka) and I use StreamBridge to send to destination.

I have verified to see if anyone has had same questions but couldnt see my exact scenario. Thank you for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solved my problems. The above log lines indicate that it was in a constant state of rebalance. The consumer was constantly trying to  switch from a topic to another since all where in the same group.

In my application yml I had not set the correct group information for the consumers.

I have several functional type KStream consumers in the StreamProcessor, to process each topic and output  as below -

```
`@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, Customer>, KStream<String,Customer>>processMessagesCustomer() {...}

@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, Supplier>, KStream<String, Supplier>>processMessagesSupplier() {...}`
```

For the STREAM PROCESSOR to create separate StreamThread it should be set to as below

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.stream.binder.functions:
    processMessagesCustomer.applicationId: <<spring.application.id>>customer
    processMessagesSupplier.applicationId: <<spring.application.id>>supplier
```

In the logs previously it was showing same consumer id

```
clientId=app1-0c725685-e7e5-47db-9d20-b8bab43d9eaa-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=app1]
```

now -

```
clientId=app1-supplier-0c725685-e7e5-47db-9d20-b8bab43d9eaa-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=app1-customer]

clientId=app1-customer-0c725685-e7e5-47db-9d20-b8bab43d9eaa-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=app1-supplier]
```

Hope this helps anyone facing similar issue.